# Using R to split a structured string into multiple columns and set column names based on string values

Tags: r, string, split, multiple-columns

I have a column of character string with each row containing information for multiple columns, including the column names. Every cell is structured so one can easily see the different pieces of information, but it is not easy to work with in this format. A cell is formatted like 'variable: value', with multiple inputs separated by commas. I would like to split the column into separate columns with the column names based on what's written before the colon. Here's an example.

```
my_df <- tibble(
address = c("street: AvenueName, number: 1, code: 1234 AB, city: City One", 
"street: AnotherStreet, number: 99, code: 5678 CD, city: Town Two")
)
```

I know I can split strings by using `separate_wider_delim` and then assign the column names to the data.frame. While this works, I would like to see a method that does not depend on setting the column names 'manually', but derive them from the values inside the string.

My expected dataframe would look like this:

```
expected_df <- tibble(
street= c("AvenueName", "AnotherStreet"),
number = c(1, 99),
code = c("1234 AB", "5678 CD"),
city = c("City One", "Town Two")
)
```

Comment: How did you manage to place `code` and `codee` together? or even `city` and `plaats` together? This looks like a dcf file. Just transform it to correct dcf and use `read.dcf` eg `read.dcf(textConnection(gsub(", *|$", "\n", my_df$address)), all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without hard-coding column names, here is one approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_df %>%
  #To keep track of each row of data 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  # Bring data in separate rows splitting on comma
  separate_rows(address, sep = ",\\s*") %>%
  # Split data on colon to get data in two columns
  separate_wider_delim(address, ": ", names = c("col", "value")) %>%
  # Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  # Drop row column
  select(-row)

#  street        number code    city    
#  <chr>         <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 AvenueName    1      1234 AB City One
#2 AnotherStreet 99     5678 CD Town Two
```

**data**

I have taken the liberty to fix your data to match it with the expected output.

```
my_df <- tibble(
  address = c("street: AvenueName, number: 1, code: 1234 AB, city: City One", 
            "street: AnotherStreet, number: 99, code: 5678 CD, city: Town Two")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the question has `codee` rather than `code` in the second line of the input.  We have kept that.  If that is corrected the code will give the corresponding corrected output.

**1)** Convert each line to dcf format by replacing comma space and end of line with newline and then use read.dcf.  If a character matrix is ok then we can omit the last two lines or if a data.frame with all character columns is ok then we can omit the last line.

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  mutate(address = gsub(", |$", "\n", address)) %>%
  { textConnection(.$address) } %>%
  read.dcf %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
         street number    code     city   codee   plaats
1    AvenueName      1 1234 AB City One    <NA>     <NA>
2 AnotherStreet     99    <NA>     <NA> 5678 CD Town Two
```

**2)** or using only base R:

```
my_df |>
  transform(address = gsub(", |$", "\n", address)) |>
  with(textConnection(address)) |>
  read.dcf() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

or without pipes

```
mat <- read.dcf(textConnection(gsub(", |$", "\n", my_df$address)))
type.convert(as.data.frame(mat), as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The strings in `my_df$address` actually can be parsed as a dictionary object in the Python manner. In that sense, you can try `py_eval` from `reticulate` + `gsub` like below

```
library(reticulate)
type.convert(
    do.call(
        rbind,
        lapply(
            sprintf(
                "{%s}",
                gsub("(\\w+):\\s([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)", "'\\1':'\\2'", my_df$address)
            ),
            \(x) list2DF(py_eval(x))
        )
    ),
    as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
         street number    code     city
1    AvenueName      1 1234 AB City One
2 AnotherStreet     99 5678 CD Town Two
```